# matlab regexp, match any character X number of times

Tags: regex, matlab

I want to

- match `a` but **not** `b`,
- any character `A-Za-z0-9` may be contained any number of times - except these characters `\@\,\.`, which may only be contained once.
- The overall matched string should be `at least 3 characters long`.

How do I achieve this? My approach doesn't work and I couldn't find the ref in the documentation for this.

```matlab
a='em@il';
b='em@@l';
%more examples
a2='em@il, test.'; %<- correct
a3='email, test';  %<- correct
b2='em@il, test,'; %<- incorrect 2x ','
b3='em@ail, test. @bc. %<- incorrect 2x '@'
regexp({a,b},'[A-Za-z0-9 (\@\,\.){1}]{3,}','match','once')
ans =

  1×2 cell array

    {'em@il'}    {'em@@l'}
```

Comment: Can you provide some examples of strings that would and wouldn't match?

Comment: `{1}` is synonymous with simply not typing it.

Comment: For `@`, `,`, and `.`: do they only invalidate the match if they each appear more than once, or would any combination of a single number of each invalidate the match? i.e. would `aaa@b,c` be invalid (because it contains two of these characters)? Or just something like `aaa@b@c`?

Comment: @CAustin eggcelent question - they don't invalidate each other, I simply want to count the occurences within the 'any' square brackets.

Comment: @NickReed updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a negative lookahead with a backreference to make sure that the dot, comma or @ do not occur twice and use a character class with a quantifier `{3,}`

```
^(?!.*([,.@]).*\1)[a-zA-Z0-9 @,.]{3,}$
```

In parts

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, if what is on the right is not

  - `.*([,.@])` Capture a `,` `.` or `@` in group 1
  - `.*\1` Match what is captured in group 1 using a backreference
- `)` Close lookahead
- `[a-zA-Z0-9 @,.]{3,}` Match any of the listed 3 or more times
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0CVscH/1)

Comment: comment on solution choice: this is easiest to read and expand, all of the solutions should be accepted (upvoted all). Thanks to everyone, it made me realize the potential of negative lookaheads

Answer (score 2):

Maybe,

```
^(?!.*@.*@|.*,.*,|.*\..*\.)[A-Za-z0-9 @,.]{3,}$
```

would be close to what you have in mind, if I understand it right.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/OTPrN9/1/)

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/OTPrN9/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/OTPrN9/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

#### Source

[MATLAB Regular Expressions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/regular-expressions.html)

Comment: Regex doesn't check for `\.` and will match strings with two or more `.` in them. To be fair, OP doesn't specify this in his examples, but does include it in the requirements. *"[...] except these characters `\@\,\.,` which may only be contained once."*

Answer (score 1):

`(?!.*(,|\.|@).*\1.*)^[a-zA-Z0-9 @,\.]{3,}$`

This regex allows any number >=3 of `a-zA-Z0-9 @,.` to be matched, but uses a negative lookahead to assert that `,.@` are only matched once in the regex. This is easy to expand - if you want to restrict additional characters, simply add them to the first capture group.

- `(?!.*(,|\.|@).*\1.*)` Assert that: if one of `,.@` is found, it is not present anywhere else in the match.
- `^[a-zA-Z0-9 @,\.]{3,}$` Between the start and end of the line, match three or more valid characters from the list.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bPDy8o/2/)